# Is it possible to apply the same context to many functions?

Tags: javascript, call, this

Is there a way to bind the same 'this' context to different functions?

```
var obj = {'a':1, 'b':2 };    

init.call(obj);

function init()
{
  func1.call(this);
  func2.call(this);
  func3.call(this);
  etc...
}
```

Preferred syntax:

```
function init()
{
  // each function should use this.
  func1();
  func2();
  func3();
  etc...
}
```

Not really a problem per se, just syntactic sugar and DRY; thanks in advance.

Edit: Thanks to Barmar, I came up with this:

```
[ func1, func2, etc... ].forEach( function(func){ func.call(this); }.bind(this));
```

Comment: Does `binding` solve your problem? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: Why not just write `func1(this)` `func2(this)`? Then your arg can be `func1(parent)` or something like that.

Comment: @Shan Robertson - I prefer: func1() { this.a = 3; }; Rather than func1(self) { self.a = 3; }; The first one is much cleaner imo.

Comment: @Data thats what binding is for, the this will refer to the bound argument.

Comment: @somethinghere - binding just gives persistence for context; I'd still have to use call for each function. btw, i'm using require, so these functions are in different modules.

Comment: @Data since `this` is bound to the current scope, you cannot actually do it in any other way. However, defining a variable inside your `init()` means that could be a shared variable when those functions are called, but they can't use the keywords `this`. But calling it when the variable is undefined would cause issues. The best solutions are already suggested in these comments.

Comment: Ya, unfortunately `this` sometimes just has to be stored or passed along the chain, esp if you are separating out into modules with require or browserify or something.

Comment: var bound = init.bind(obj); bound(); I'd still need to call each function with call.

Comment: @Shan Robertson - figured as much, thought there was an ECMA6 special function or similar. Can you write your comment as an answer and i'll mark it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a function that does it:

```
function callAll() {
    var funcArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    for (var i = 0; i < funcArray.length; i++) {
        funcArray[i].call(this);
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
callAll.call(obj, func1, func2, func3);
```

Comment: That's genius, so simple, but it works.  var funcs = [ func1, func2, func3, etc... ]; for (var i=0; i<funcs.length; i++) funcs[i].call(this);

Comment: Finally ended up with this: var funcs = [ func1, func2 ].forEach( function(func){ func.call(this); }.bind(this));